# How to determine what happened and locate the problem when my system freezes?

Tags: 10.04, freeze, troubleshooting, debugging

Hello I had some freezes with my desktop. It is Lucid 10.04 on a Lenovo 3000 N200. System freezes completely.

How can I locate the problem?

Comment: can you install `hardinfo` (http://hardinfo.berlios.de/HomePage) from software center and paste a report here?

Comment: Can you still use a magic sysrq key (like `Alt + Print + K` to restart X? Another good start is `~/xsession.errors` and `dmesg` / `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: In 95% cases that linux freezes its a hardware problem, of course if you didn't mess with the system. Check the temperature of you CPU, GPU, system and if all fans are getting air. Also try to find out the usage pattern that causes freeze and check /var/log/messages and system status with dmesg

Comment: When it freezes, hit caps lock and num-lock and see if the keyboard lights change. If so, then X has frozen rather than the hardware.

Comment: @Roland Taylor.  What should I paste here exactly? Devices, Memory, Filesystem?

Comment: save a full report, by clicking summary, and then clicking generate report. it will give you an html file to save, and you can then upload this to pastebin.com, dropbox, or ubuntuone (as examples) and drop us a link here.

Comment: Following Roland's most recent comment above, make sure to edit your original question to include the link to your paste.  You can also try using netconsole, which I find useful (http://sarah.thesharps.us/2010-03-26-09-41).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes it's just the X server that is frozen. Try to get a console by hitting `CTRL-ALT-F1`. If that won't do, try logging it your machine using SSH (install openssh-server package first). If you can't get a shell, reboot.

Once you have a shell, check the system logs (`/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `~/.xsession-errors`). Scroll up to the time the crash happened. If you didn't have to reboot, the `dmesg` command will show you the kernel log buffer in case it can't write to your filesystem.

Whether or not you are able to find anything in the log file, what makes it easier to debug is being able to reproduce the problem at will. If you can't, and the logs show nothing unusual, then you can try to isolate the source of the problem by booting a rescue CD (or a completely different OS), removing non-essential pieces of hardware, or replacing some parts with others that are known to be functionnal. Doing this can be tedious, and requires rigour.

Once you have minimal information, file a bug report for the suspected faulty software, unless you think your hardware is faulty.