# What can I do when Ubuntu freezes for some unknown mysterious reasons?

Tags: freeze, troubleshooting, debugging

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 but of some unknown reason sometime Ubuntu get stuck, no motion what so ever. If i try to move a mouse it doesn't respond and same thing with the keyboard.

I hope at least some one gives some reply bcoz I'm not getting replies on most of my questions.

Comment: Please share the output of the following files and/or commands with us [using the instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): command `dmesg`, file `/var/log/kern.log`

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes?rq=1 -- http://askubuntu.com/questions/13726/how-to-determine-what-happened-and-locate-the-problem-when-my-system-freezes?rq=1

Comment: What version do you have (32 or 64)? Do you have all the requirements to run Ubuntu (RAM - CPU speed - graphics)?

Comment: System Specifications
I have Quad core , 
RAM 4 GM , 
Motherboard Gigbyte,
Graphics card Nvidia 
Ubuntu 32 bit version

@izx And i have run the Pastebinit command the Log file URL is http://paste.ubuntu.com/1055557/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Unity Freezes, You can just use this shortcut to find yourself at Login Screen again.

**The Shortcut key combination** : <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.

Hope this will answer your question.

You can also see this answer: [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes/36717#36717)

Comment: ok I'll keep this info in mind . But in my case keyboard and mouse also freeze , but i will give this a try . Thnx dear

Comment: I often do `sudo stop lightdm` followed by `sudo start lightdm` but  this sounds better.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in with your username and password. Then type `kill -9 -1`. This will bring terminate all programs and services run as your user (while leaving system programs and services alone). Then switch back to the login screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and now you can login to your account.

If your work is not saved and you want to kill only frozen programs, rather than everything, then type `top` and look and see which is your frozen program, and to kill the process.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever my machine freezes I try to do CTRL+ALT+F5 or any of the F1-F6 keys to see if you can switch to another terminal instance.  If you can, then you can try and kill the unresponsive program from the terminal.  If you can't, which in your case with the mouse not moving is highly likely, then you may be having an issue unrelated to processes.

If the latter is the case then here's some good information for you:

[What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Answer (score 0):

A few more details about the story of your machine might be helpful. For instance, is it a new Laptop? If not, did it use to work well before you installed 12.04?

So I just assume the Laptop is new. Based on my very personal experience, it *might* be that you are experiencing a RAM failure. I bought a Laptop and I installed Ubuntu (11.04 at that time) on it. I started experiencing some random freezes, like those you described (mouse cursor not moving, keyboard not responding). I turned out that it was an hardware problem and I had to give that Laptop back. Running a memtest might shed some light on your case.

Answer (score 0):

Guess some updates could be missing. First, type:

> sudo apt-get update

in a Terminal [**Ctrl+At+T**]and thereafter see whether there are any updates available, via *Update Manager* (available from the top right hand gear icon). Also, you can select the best server for download of updates depending on your location (from **Software Sources**). Here, select what kind of updates are to be downloaded and installed. It is best if important security updates are allowed to be installed without confirmation. Installing regular updates may sometimes solve issues affecting performance.